# How to get result from multiple query on multiple collection of mongo in eventBus vertx2?

Tags: java, mongodb, vert.x

I am working on providing API and I am storing data by month a database and by date a collection on mongodb.

So I have db `db_08_2015` then I have 31 collection from `date_01` to `date_31`
and I have to query data from date 1 to date 10 to have a  total money spend so I need to send 31 request like this.

My question is How to get data by 1 request at the time to get a sum before I return to client like sync request into mongo to get result.
Something like I have date_01 = 10 then date_02 = 20 ... and I want to sum it all before return to client.

```
vertx.eventBus().send("mongodb-persistor", json, new Handler<Message<JsonObject>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(Message<JsonObject> message) {
                    logger.info(message.body());
                    JsonObject result = new JsonObject(message.body().encodePrettily());
                    JsonArray r = result.getArray("results");
                    if (r.isArray()) {
                        if (r.size() > 0) {
                            String out = r.get(0).toString();
                            req.response().end(out);
                        } else {
                            req.response().end("{}");
                        }
                    } else {
                        req.response().end(message.body().encodePrettily());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Well you've pretty much said all there is to know yourself. Your collections are separate, so rather than the database doing all the work you will need to code the logic to aggregate yourself in your API. Which means multiple calls to the database. I struggle to see the cases where this is a good design or even necessary for scale. It is in fact why solutions like "sharding" exist, to allow distributed loads. Even with one collection.

Comment: @BlakesSeven thank you for recommending but in my case data is a lot I have to separate into date.

Comment: You would not be the only person ever who does. The point is simple. MongoDB in particular can only work on one collection at a time, thus ruling out any "database help" from the sort of aggregation you want to do. If you want the most efficient database end, then use a singular collection and look at other means for scaling. Otherwise, it's all up to your code to retrieve and aggregate just the raw data read, and in multiple reads. Aggregation here is a simple concept. Just as HashMap and keep accumulating the data on matched keys. But you will still need to make many requests.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Thank you very much I understand your idea. 
My idea is total wrong we need a collection to store the aggregate result to query and db_month coll_day just for store raw data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case you might be better off by having a different approach to model your data.
In terms of analytics I would recommend the lambda architecture approach as quoted below:

[image: Lambda Architecture diagram]

> - All data entering the system is dispatched to both the batch layer and the speed layer for processing.
> - The batch layer has two functions: (i) managing the master dataset (an immutable, append-only set of raw data), and (ii) to pre-compute
>     the batch views.
> - The serving layer indexes the batch views so that they can be queried in low-latency, ad-hoc way.
> - The speed layer compensates for the high latency of updates to the serving layer and deals with recent data only.
> - Any incoming query can be answered by merging results from batch views and real-time views.

Having the above in mind, why not have an aggregates collection that should hold the aggregated data in the format your query requires, while at the same time keep a raw copy in the format you described.

By having this you will have a view over the data in the required query format and a way to recreate the aggregated data in case your system backfires.

References for diagram and quotes - [Lambda Architecture](http://lambda-architecture.net/)